# Receiving WebHooks to MS CRM Dynamics

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, webhooks

I need to be able to recieve a webhook from Azure, and then change a simple status field inside MS CRM Dynamics.

I´ve been reading this tutorial from [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2016/01/15/sending-webhooks-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm/):

But what I dont understand in this tutorial is when the Webhook will trigger in my CRM? Do I have to register the WebHook on a certain step in CRM? What I want is that it should trigger directly when my WebHook recieves a request. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The link you referred (sending webhook from crm to web app) is exact opposite of your requirement (sending webhook to crm).

Your requirement can be achieved simply using CRM plugin (or workflow). If the webhook is going to create/update record in crm, registering plugin on create/update message (pre or post operation) will suffice.

As such there is no Azure webhook available to trigger this. You can do Azure web app or Logic app with CRM connector to manipulate data.

Comment: Thank you Arun for you reply.So basically, my requirment is that I will send a document to an external source, and when it is ready to be consumed (a couple of days later), the CRM will fetch it from the external source, and then change a status to 'Completed' in MS CRM Dynamics (online).

So in that case, can I use a plugin that consumes the webhook? And when it retrieves a incoming request, my plugin can simply change the status? Or I´m a missing something?

Comment: Arun, did u noticed that there is a section for receiving web hooks in the link I refered to?

Comment: CRM(sender) & Web app(receiver) are 2 connected pieces in that link. You have 4 disconnected pieces: doc to ext source (1), doc ready after 2 days (2), crm fetch it (3) and status change (4). Can you bridge these ? Who send doc in step 1, crm? If so webhook will help as in link. How does crm fetch it in step 3? Answer to this question may help me to answer how to design the plugin to change status.. @Chris111

Comment: [Step 1:] CRM will send the doc. [Step 3:] The ext. source will send the webhook that I preferably would like to listen to directly on in MS CRM. Otherwise if not possible I´m thinking second best option might be to listen to the Webhook from a Azure Function and then change the status in MS CRM from there. What do you think? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Chris111 Absolutely.. Azure function is the best choice.. https://nishantrana.me/2017/04/28/call-dynamics-crm-from-azure-functions/

Comment: OK great! Just curious, would it be possible to do it directly in MS CRM without Azure Function?

Comment: @Chris111 what’s your control over ext source? Can you make a CRM service call from there directly?

Comment: Good point, that was actually my first suggestion. But as i´m not in fully control over it and they don´t want to do anything "out of standard" from there point of view, even if it would be easier from my side. So that is not an option unfortunately.